# how to list all row keys in an hbase table?

Tags: hbase

Can anybody tell me, how to list all row keys in an hbase table?

Comment: Do you want to list all row keys through the hbase shell or through the Java API?

Comment: Hi  knt ,i need to list using REST-PHP combination. Can u help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look here http://hbase.apache.org/docs/r0.20.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/stargate/package-summary.html#operation_scanner_create

Answer (score 31):

The HBase shell could be used to list all the row keys:

```
count 'table_name', { INTERVAL => 1 }
```

Answer (score 15):

This should be considerably faster (the FirstKeyOnlyFilter is run on the server and strips all the column data before sending the result to the client):

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName.getBytes());
System.out.println("scanning full table:");
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setFilter(new FirstKeyOnlyFilter());
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
for (Result rr : scanner) {
  byte[] key == rr.getRow();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Correct, but `scan.setCaching(1000)` is far **more crucial** than just using `FirstKeyOnlyFilter`. Please note that default caching is set to `1`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName.getBytes());

System.out.println("scanning full table:");
ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(new Scan());
for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr = scanner.next()) {
  byte[] key == rr.getRow();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Pardon me.. I need the REST API-PHP way to do the same.

Answer (score 2):

When performing a table scan where only the row keys are needed (no families, qualifiers, values or timestamps), add a FilterList with a MUST_PASS_ALL operator to the scanner using setFilter. The filter list should include both a FirstKeyOnlyFilter and a KeyOnlyFilter. Using this filter combination will result in a worst case scenario of a RegionServer reading a single value from disk and minimal network traffic to the client for a single row.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [getRow](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html#getRow--) method of Result class. Its description says:

> Method for retrieving the row key that corresponds to the row from
>   which this Result was created.

Assuming `table` is your hbase table and you are connected to your HBase instance, all you need to do is:

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
ResultScanner rscanner = table.getScanner(scan);
for(Result r : rscanner){
   //r is the result object that contains the row
   //do something
   System.out.println(Bytes.toString(r.getRow())); //doing something
}
```

I understand that this has already been answered from Java API point of view but a little more detail never hurt anyone.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to use HBase thrift client in PHP. Here is a sample code and you can get all data in HBase and get their row keys.

```
<? $_SERVER['PHP_ROOT'] = realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/..');
   require_once $_SERVER['PHP_ROOT'].'/flib/__flib.php';
   flib_init(FLIB_CONTEXT_SCRIPT);
   require_module('storage/hbase');
   $hbase = new HBase('<server_name_running_thrift_server>', <port on which thrift server is running>);
   $hbase->open();
   $client = $hbase->getClient();
   $result = $client->scannerOpenWithFilterString('table_name', "(PrefixFilter ('row2') AND (QualifierFilter (>=, 'binary:xyz'))) AND (TimestampsFilter ( 123, 456))");
   $to_print = $client->scannerGetList($result,1);
   while ($to_print) {
      print_r($to_print);
      $to_print = $client->scannerGetList($result,1);
    }
   $client->scannerClose($result);
?>
```